# Create QueryDef without a name in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

What does it exactly mean, when I am create a QueryDef without a name? Does it mean, that the query exists only as long as a reference to it is set?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Read on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createquerydef-method-dao

> You can create a **temporary QueryDef** by using a zero-length string for the name argument when you execute the CreateQueryDef method. You can also accomplish this by setting the Name property of a newly created QueryDef to a zero-length string ("").
>
> Temporary QueryDef objects are useful if you want to repeatedly use dynamic SQL statements without having to create any new permanent objects in the QueryDefs collection.

In particular, if you want to execute a parameterized query.

Once there is no more reference set to it (e.g. a recordset based on it), a temporary querydef is automatically deleted (= ceases to exist).